# Custom Button On WooCommerce Single Product Page For Specific Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

Hello This Below Code is working fine but this is not inline to "Add to Cart" button. I Want This Custom Button To Inline Add To Cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_button_by_categories', 36 ,0 );
function custom_button_by_categories(){
    
    global $product;

    // Define your categories in this array (can be Ids, slugs or names)
    $product_cats = array('mobile-touch', 'music', 'furnitures');

    if( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
         $demo_url = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'demo_url', true );
         echo '<a class="fancybox iframe" data-width="1280" data-height="820" a href="https://lab.dmarket.pk/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><button style="background: #007bc4; color: #ffffff; border-radius: 5px;margin-top: -120px !important;margin-left: 220px !important; padding-left: 19px; padding-right: 19px;"> Fix My Device</button></a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `woocommerce_single_product_summary` with `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` should do the job